# How to make ZSH tab completion work with two tabs

Tags: shell, zsh, autocomplete

I saw a question like this on here, but the answer didn't work for me.  I'm trying to set up tab completion and I want it that if I have two files `fileA` and `fileB` and I type `fil<tab>` it first replaces the text with `file` and then after pressing tab again, it should bring up the menu and highlight the first option, `fileA`.

I've tried `menu_complete`, which selects `fileA` on the first tab, but does expand to the ambiguous form first (and I sometimes like typing *).  `auto_menu` requires 3 tabs to complete, the first fills out the `file` part, the second brings up the menu, and the third brings up `fileA`.

This is my zshrc http://pastebin.com/e0BLL1F2

Any ideas?  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

What version of zsh are you using?

Have you tried without any .zshrc at all? Because with the version of ZSH I have here this is the default behaviour - without further configuration.